# How to check if user liked my page before loading my app?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-apps

hi i have a facebook page and app.

when new user loading facebook app, it needs to check is he already liked to my fb page. if not user liked to it need to popup message to like page.

thanks for you time..

Comment: Without having the user connect to your app and giving permission first, this is only possible within a Page Tab app on Facebook. (As for how – please do some research.)

Answer (score 2):

You could issue the following request (if you before gathered the "user_likes" permissions for your app, and a respective access token):

```
GET /{user-id}/likes/{page-id}
```

with {user-id} as "me" and {page-id} as the page_id of your page as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/common-scenarios#pagelikes